# Getting Equation to Find a Perfect Square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm trying to work through the explanation of [Ferrari's Solution of the Quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari.27s_solution).

The arbitrary variable: $y$ is introduced to the depressed quartic in the link's step **3**, yielding a right side of: $$(\alpha + 2y)u^2 - \beta u + (y^2 + 2\alpha y + \alpha^2 - \gamma)$$

Then the statement is then made that:

> As the value of $y$ may be arbitrarily chosen, we will choose it in order to get a perfect square in the right-hand side. This implies that the discriminant in $u$ of this quadratic equation is zero, that is $y$ is a root of the equation

Somehow that yields the equation: $$(-\beta)^2 - 4(2y + \alpha)(y^2 + 2\alpha y + \alpha^2 - \gamma) = 0$$

I need help seeing what was done to achieve that jump. Can someone explain to me how we just decided that this equation could be used to solve for $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite the equation as 
$$(\alpha+2y) \left (u^2 + \frac{-\beta}{\alpha+2y} u + \frac{y^2+2\alpha y + \alpha^2 - \gamma^2}{\alpha+2y}\right ).$$
In order for 
$$\left (u^2 + \frac{-\beta}{\alpha+2y} u + \frac{y^2+2\alpha y + \alpha^2 - \gamma^2}{\alpha+2y}\right )\qquad(*)$$
 to be a perfect square we must have that
$$\left(\frac{-\beta}{2(\alpha+2y)}\right)^2 = \frac{y^2+2\alpha y + \alpha^2 - \gamma^2}{\alpha+2y}$$
or equivalently
$$(-\beta)^2- 4(\alpha+2y)(y^2+2\alpha y + \alpha^2 - \gamma^2)=0.$$
This means that $(*)$ will be a perfect square whenever $y$ is a solution to this last equation.